# In the proof of the Yoneda Lemma in "Categories & Sheaves" by Kashiwara & Schapira.

Tags: category-theory, functors, morphism, yoneda-lemma

Our goal is to show that $\text{Hom}_{C^{\wedge}}(h_C(X), A) \simeq A(X)$.

We first want to show a map from left to right.

The book says:

$$
\text{Hom}_{C^{\wedge}}(h_C(X), A) \to \text{Hom}_{\text{Set}}(\text{Hom}_C(X,X), A) \to A(X)
$$

I'm wondering what the first mapping is, and why the subscript changes to $\text{Set}$, and how do they justify that step?

Thanks.

Comment: Other than it should be $A(X)$ in the second argument to $\text{Hom}_{\text{Set}}$, this is just picking the component at $X$ of the natural transformations. You can view it as a projection from a limit if you like.

Comment: @DerekElkins so is that a typo in the book?

Comment: @DerekElkins how is this map usually written?  $\circ X$?

Comment: If you accurately transcribed from the book, then yes, it's a typo. If I was going to notate the projection, I'd either notate it as a projection $\pi_X$, or, more likely for this context, notate it as $(\_)_X$, as in $\alpha\mapsto\alpha_X$.

Comment: @DerekElkins it isn't a typo :P  I transcribed wrong